# Selenium JS Executor Failure: "Failed to execute elementsFromPoint on Document"

Tags: java, selenium

I'm running code that fetches a span by the value of its text and then goes to rightclick it using this function:

```java
public void rightClickElement(WebElement element) {
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        actions.contextClick(element).perform();
    }
```

Basically I iterate over a list of filenames and select the element I want to manipulate by its filename by using the following XPATH:

```
//span[contains(text(), 'PLACEHOLDER')]
```

with a function that replaces PLACEHOLDER by the current value of the array of filenames I'm iterating over.

This is my code:

*Note: `getAssertedElement` is just a function I wrote that asserts an element's existence and returns it at the same time.

```java
List<WebElement> textFilesElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[(@class='document') and contains(text(), '.txt')]"));
ArrayList<String> filesToDelete = new ArrayList<String>();
waitSeconds(1);
for (int i = 0; i < textFilesElements.size(); i++) {
    filesToDelete.add(textFilesElements.get(i).getText());
}

for (int i = 0; i < filesToDelete.size(); i++) {
    WebElement elementToDelete = getAssertedElement("Cannot find the current element",
            replacePlaceholderInString(
                    "//span[contains(text(), 'PLACEHOLDER')]",
                    filesToDelete.get(i)
                    ),
            "xpath");
    System.out.println("FICHIER TO DELETE" + elementToDelete.getText());
    rightClickElement(elementToDelete);
    // do things with element
    ...
}
```

This works fine the first time through the second `for` statement, but when I move on to the next filename, even though the element is visible and clickable, the test fails with the following error when it reaches the `rightClickElement` call:

```
javascript error: Failed to execute 'elementsFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
```

I don't understand why, much less how to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried highlighting the `elementToDelete` and see if it's getting the right element?

Comment: Can you also share your ```replacePlaceholderInString``` method?